# How to write lines to a text file thread safe - multi threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, thread-safety, streamwriter

I just tried this and it failed

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        writeFile();
    });

}

TextWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("deneme.txt");

void writeFile()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
    {
        int irTempPara = k;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            writeFileForReal(irTempPara);
        });
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

void writeFileForReal(int srParameter)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 999999999; k++)
    {
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(srParameter + "_" + k);
    }
}
```

It is c# 4.5 WPF application

So what method would you suggest for writing lines to a text file most effeciently and multi threading

Comment: Do you need to preserve order of lines?

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/01/28/tpl-dataflow-walkthrough-part-5.aspx

Comment: IamStalker nope. line order not important.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about this?

```
TextWriter.Synchronized(myWriter).WriteLine("Hello World!!!");
```

Comment: Your objective should be thread safety, rather than efficiency if efficiency means performance. Because of the physical structure of common hard drives (except RAID), multiple threading in writing file won't speed up overall performance. The disk is spinning with the r/w head moving, so all read/write requests are actually synchronized.

Comment: ok i am trying single line writing with another software. line never appears on the text file. why might it be happening ?

Comment: like this one :  txtWriterMultiThread.WriteLine("asdsadas" + "_" ); just single line writing but never appears on notepad file. it is empty

Comment: Overall I see your codes use System.Threading.Tasks which is for parallel programming, while your use case seem just need asynchronous call. And I would recommend that you read some articles about parallel programming, at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx. With asynchronous calls, you may have a helper function with such implementation: Action d=()=>{TextWriter.Synchronized(myWriter).WriteLine(...);}; d.BeginInvoke(null, null);

Answer (score 2):

You can just use simple TPL way as you do, but you can set:

```
    void writeFile()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
        {
            int irTempPara = k;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                writeFileForReal(irTempPara);
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); // this way you do not need sleep
            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

http://coderkarl.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/long-running-tasks-and-threads/

Comment: what does exactly TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning doing ?

Answer (score 1):

You must never rely on Sleep for synchronization in multi threading. Instead, take in consideration to use a synchronization mechanism such as a [semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) or a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Comment: niculare that is not really important here. i am trying to write multi threaded :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Um no it's _absolutely_ important. If you want to "write multi threaded" then you _need_ to understand this.

Comment: Consider a named semaphore, because then you can use it across processes (i.e. if you have a webgarden) and also if you use async/await pattern, it can return on a different thread, which will cause a deadlock for a mutex because only the thread that obtains the mutex can release it.